# What role does dummy variable play in this example?

Tags: change-of-variable

> It's an IVP in Separation Equations :
> $$\frac {dy}{dx}=e^{-x^2}, y(3)=5$$
> Here is the solution on text:
> $$\int^x_3\frac {dy}{dt}dt=\int_3^xe^{-t^2}dt$$
> It comes out
> $$y(x)=y(3)+\int_3^xe^{-t^2}dt$$
> And here is my answer with steps
> $$\int^x_3dy=\int^x_3e^{-x^2}dx$$
> $$y]^x_3=\int^x_3e^{-x^2}dx$$
> $$y(x)-y(3)=\int^x_3e^{-x^2}dx$$
> And they were in my opinion the same. So why bother using dummy variable? Did I ignore any concept?

Comment: The issue is that as it is you've used $x$ as your variable for integration and in the bounds, so it's both free and bound in that context which really just doesn't make any sense from a notational standpoint. We use the dummy variable for the integration because it makes it a lot clearer which $x$'s are for our integration and which refer to the more global way you use $x$ here.

Comment: @StephenDonovan but on the LHS. Why using (dy/dt)/dt? that is so unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that we must not mixed up the limits of an integral and the differential coefficient which denotes by which the integration will be evaluated.

For example, $$\int_{1}^21d1$$ is meaning less no one treats $1$ as a variable.

Another is $$\int_{0}^xx^2dx$$ is meaning less as the limit is $x$ and we are integrating w.r.t. $x$. Confusion may arise since after evaluation we get $$\left[\frac{t^3}{3}\right]_{x=0}^{x=x}$$ see that $x=x$ term?? Very confusing as it gives $0=0$. That's why *Dummy variable* is used i.e. $$\int_{0}^xt^2dt=\left[\frac{x^3}{3}\right]_{t=0}^{t=x}$$ see? No classical confusion arises for this notation.

Comment: Thanks, I knew that and I was not very precise up there, the real problem is on the LHS where it wrote (dy/dt)dt. I can't understand the purpose of this work.